# Win XP Network drivers for an HP dx7200

Tags: networking, windows-xp, drivers

I recently reinstalled Windows XP SP3 from scratch on an (old) HP dx7200. So far so good.

However, I'm unable to get the integrated networking to work. I've searched the HP drivers page for this model, but there are so many drivers listed that I don't know what I need to install.

I've tried installing a handful of networking and chipset drivers, but to no avail.

Has anyone successfully reinstalled Win XP from scratch on an old HP like this?

Comment: Anyone able to tell me why this got downvoted? Wrong forum? Bad form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has anyone successfully reinstalled Win XP from scratch on an old HP
>   like this?

Just download the following drivers:

[Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Drivers for Microsoft Windows XP](ftp://ftp.hp.com//pub/softpaq/sp42001-42500/sp42471.exe)

[Intel Gigabit Network Connection Drivers for Microsoft Windows XP](ftp://ftp.hp.com//pub/softpaq/sp41501-42000/sp41804.exe)

[Belkin Wireless NIC Driver](ftp://ftp.hp.com//pub/softpaq/sp39001-39500/sp39228.exe)

Of course Dell offers a [tool](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp59501-60000/sp59568.exe) and also [this](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/HP_SDM_Setup.exe) that downloads and installs all the required drivers for you I would just use that.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Installing the drivers isn't a novice task (some of them are the "have disk" type) but cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear there is a tool to help automate driver installation, but without a network connection, I imagine it'd be a bit hamstrung.

Comment: @aaaidan - Technically you shouldn't need drivers for the internet to work.  But the task of downloading drivers is trivial.  **I don't even have the computer in question and I was able to figure it out.**

Comment: My, you're a friendly fellow! I can assure that there was no Internet connection before installing the drivers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @aaaidan - I assure you I am very friendly.